# Which or Apply function in R

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that:

given the current index of a vector `vect[i] == 0`, if `vect[i+1] > 0`, it will return `TRUE`. Else, return `FALSE`.

I know how to write it out using a for-loop to traverse the whole vector. However, I am interested in more **efficient** ways of doing this, i.e. write a simple function like the following and then pass it to `which()` or `apply()` function ?

```
ia <- function(x) {
    if(vect[i] == 0) {
        if(vect[i+1] > 0) {
            return TRUE
        } else {
            return FALSE
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. How can make it work such that I can pass the above function into a which function or any better functions you can come up with?

Comment: How should the function behave at the last element of the vector where `vect[i+1]` doesn't exist?

Comment: As I said, I could easily run a for-loop from 1 to length(vect) - 1. But I am interested in more efficient methods.

Comment: You never define `i` in your function.  Is it supposed to be an input?  Why don't you give some example input and output?  Because to me I don't see why you don't just work with `vect > 0` or `vect[-1] > 0` directly

Comment: I don't understand what `given the current index of a vector vect[i] == 0` means. What is equal to 0?

Comment: I mean, current index is "i" and vect[i] == 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
ia <- function(x) c(x[-length(x)] == 0 & x[-1] > 0, FALSE)

x <- c(1, 3, 0, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, -3, 4, 0, 1, 0, -3, 10)

ia(x)
 [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[11]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE


cbind(x, ia(x))
       x  
 [1,]  1 0
 [2,]  3 0
 [3,]  0 1
 [4,]  3 0
 [5,]  4 0
 [6,]  5 0
 [7,]  0 0
 [8,]  0 0
 [9,] -3 0
[10,]  4 0
[11,]  0 1
[12,]  1 0
[13,]  0 0
[14,] -3 0
[15,] 10 0
```

We can also get the index using `which`

```
which(ia(x))
[1]  3 11
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
vect[which(vect==0) + 1] > 0
```

Comment: It does work. It returns an `NA` if the last number is `0`, which is exactly what it should do since we don't know the significance of `vect`.

Comment: @SeñorO I wasn't so much concerned about edge cases, as about the fact that this doesn't produce what OP seemed to want (c.f. with dickoa's answer to see what "right" output should be)

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume you want the last element of your vector to return `TRUE` if it is == 0 irrelevant of the "following" value.  I'd make a shifted vector and do two comparisons:

```
vect <- rbinom(10, 1, prob=0.5)
shifted <- c(vect[-1],0)
```

Then do your comparison:

```
result <- vect == 0 & shifted > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways:

```
k <- c(0,1,0,2,0,0,3,0)
result <- c(mapply(function(x,y) x == 0 & y > 0, head(k, -1), tail(k, -1)), FALSE)
```

and

```
c(apply(embed(k,2), 1, function(row) row[1] > 0 & row[2] == 0), FALSE)
```

`tail` and `head` with `-1` arguments return all but the first and last elements, respectively, you can use this to compare the value at each index to the one after it. `embed` with argument `2` creates a two column matrix of the vector, where the last column includes all but the last element and the second column is lagged by 1.